# vba access filtering function

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, filter

I am using Access and mssql.
I am trying to make filtering function like below picture.
When I type 'S', related data should be showed.

[image]

To make this function, I made the code like this. (After updating the textbox, it calls function 'CreateFilter'.) There are other fields, but I think I can make it work if I know how this function work. So I just attached one field's code.

```vb
Sub Createfilter()

Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim strConn As String
Dim par As ADODB.Parameter           'input

strConn = "DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=CHU-AS-0004;DATABASE=RTC_LaplaceD_DEV;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"

Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.Open strConn               'open connection


Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim introw
Dim strState As String
Dim str As String
Dim str1 As String
Dim str2 As String
Dim str3 As String
Dim str4 As String
Dim andboolean As Boolean 'decide to add "AND" to the sql string or not

andboolean = False 'initialze
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

str = "SELECT * FROM dbo.PilotRequest WHERE"
' RequestID
    str1 = " RequestID Like '"
    If IsNull(Filter1.value) Then str2 = "" Else str2 = Filter1.value
    str3 = "%' "
    str4 = str & str1 & str2 & str3
    MsgBox ("Str4" & str4)

    rs.Open str4, conn

    conn.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set conn = Nothing

If str = "SELECT * FROM dbo.PilotRequest WHERE" Then
    str = "SELECT * FROM dbo.PilotRequest ORDER BY dbo.PilotRequest.RequestID DESC"
End If

ListRequest.RowSource = str4


ListRequest.Requery

End Sub
```

I used MsgBox to check whether the data is correct or not. 
MsgBox looks like this.

[image]
I think the query is right, but after executing this code, it looks like this. It shows no data. There should be a data '1119' because that data is in mssql but it shows nothing. 
[image]

[image]
Could you give me some help regarding this issue?

Comment: The way your code reads now all that are doing is providing a query string to `ListRequest`.  If the database isn't connected to 'RTC_LaplaceD_DEV' then you won't get any results.

Comment: My code is connected to the 'RTC_LaplaceD_DEV' and in other pages, it works fine. So I don't think it is connecting issue.

Answer (score 1):

No *RequestID* seems to start with "1" so try:

```
str1 = " RequestID Like '????1"
str2 = Nz(Filter1.value)
str3 = "*' "
```

If filtering from the first character:

```
str1 = " RequestID Like '"
str2 = Nz(Filter1.value)
str3 = "*' "
```

Comment: The first picture is just an example. I want to make a program like that.